# $ \int_{-1}^{t} \frac{x + |x|}{2x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x) = \frac{x + |x|}{2x}$ for $x$ not $0$ and $f(0)=0$. How can I compute the integral $\int_{-1}^{t} f(x) dx$

I tried this: $ \int_{-1}^{t} \frac{x + |x|}{2x}dx$ = $ \int_{-1}^{t} ( \frac{x}{2} + \frac{|x|}{2x} ) dx $ = $ ( \frac{x^2}{4})|_{-1}^{t} + \int_{-1}^{t} \frac{|x|}{2x} dx$ = ?

Now f has a discontinuity in zero but  $f(0)=0$ then f is not discontinuous here. But then how can I compute this integral from $0$ to $t$ ?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You should divide the integral in its negative and positive domains, and use the definition of $x\mapsto |x|$ in each of those domains. The value of $f$ in the specific point ${0}$ doesn't matter (think about it: it's a singleton.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$
f(x) = \frac{x + |x|}{2x}.
$$

Remember the definition of $|x|$
$$
|x| = \begin{cases} x, \ x\geq0 \\ -x, \ x<0. \end{cases}
$$

Assume $t<0$, then

$$
\int_{-1}^{t} \frac{x-x}{2x} dx = 0.
$$

Now assum $t\geq0$ then by dividing the integral, we get

$$
\int_{1}^{t}  f(x) dx = \int_{-1}^{0^-} f(x) dx + f(0) + \int_{0^+}^{t} f(x) dx = \int_{-1}^{0^-} \frac{x - x}{2x} dx + 0 + \int_{0^+}^{t} \frac{x+x}{2x}dx = \int_{0^+}^{t} 1 dx = t - (0^+) \to t.
$$

Comment: I'm not sure that covers the case t < 0 correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I have made an edit @Hilmar

Answer (score 1):

Just draw the function and you'll see it. Your function is 
$$ f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix} 0
 & x \leq 0 \\ 1
 & x \geq  0
\end{matrix}\right. $$
which is a remarkably convoluted way to write a unit step function. So the integral is simply
$$ \int_{-1}^{t} f(x)\cdot dx = \left\{\begin{matrix} 0
 & t \leq 0 \\ t
 & t \geq  0
\end{matrix}\right. $$